# Unity - how to add video to unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to put video inside plane object

I follow tutorial on how you do that ,

1- Create new material (the video inside material ).

2- attach material to plane object

3- add script as gameController

```
  using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

      public MovieTexture movTexture;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture= movTexture;
        movTexture.Play ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


    }
}
```

but it give me error

```
Assets/Scripts/GameController.cs(9,63): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Texture' does not contain a definition for `Play' and no extension method `Play' of type `UnityEngine.Texture' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**UPDATED**
I am using unity 5.1 free , I am trying develop game for Gear VR thats run in android device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mainTexture` field](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-mainTexture.html) is of the base [`Texture`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture.html) class. If you've configured and assigned the material properly, then you can cast it to [`MovieTexture`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MovieTexture.html) where you can then call `Play()`:

```
 ((MovieTexture)GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture).Play();
```

Additional information about playing video with `MovieTexture` can be found in the manual here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html

Comment: I try this answer but I got error MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "GameController" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Renderer to the game object "GameController". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
GameController.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/GameController.cs:9)

Comment: @minafawzy: Make sure your GameController object has a Renderer component (such as "Mesh Renderer") assigned to it in the Unity Editor.

Comment: thank you , but I have another error Assets/Scripts/GameController.cs(9,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `MovieTexture' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @minafawzy: Try adding a `using UnityEngine;` line at the top of the file.

Comment: its already added using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

Comment: @minafawzy: Can you post the full source code of `GameController` then? Also, what version (and license) of Unity are you using? (e.g., "Unity 5.1 Free", or "Unity 4.6 Pro")

Comment: @minafawzy: Can you post your updated code that's giving you the new error about `MovieTexture` not being found?

Answer (score 1):

`MovieTexture` is not supported in Android. Currently there are no simple ways to play videos on android using `unity3d` other than full screen, unless you buy some assets that make video on textures possible, but no sound.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly reference for adding a video is only integrated with unity pro.

Comment: As of Unity 5, the free version also supports videos. Regardless, the error is independent of this; you would get the same error in Unity 4 Pro.